# Why the debugger is not going to next line after clicking on file download button through IE Web driver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am clicking on file download button in Internet Explorer. And Open/Save/Cancel prompt is coming. Like this

[Open and Save prompt in IE after clicking download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIKvI.png)

Code in c# for clicking on the download file button.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerWebDriver();

driver.FindElement(By.Id("Id_Download_File_Button")).Click();

Console.WriteLine("Donload Button clicked");
```

After clicking on the button the flow is not going to the next line. It stucks there. after few seconds it is throwing wedriver timeout exception.

Is there any workaround or any one have any idea. Why the webdriver is not going to next line.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

That "dialog" is browser specific and is not an HTML dialog. The code you are using is for an HTML dialog so it won't work. It gets stuck there likely because you have an `implicitWait()` set and Selenium is waiting for that to timeout and then the exception is thrown.

Comment: I removed all waits.  Now getting another exception ..  The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:.................................. /click timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: Anyone here who would help.    Button code on which I am clicking.  ` <input name="DownloadFile" value="Download File" id="btnDownloadFile" class="button" style="width:221px;" type="submit">`    after clicking, web driver is waiting for some kind of response. And throwing exception after 60 seconds.

Comment: Please update your question with the HTML in the comment above and any other details that you have regarding this question including error and exception details.